# interpreter contents of email to mysql record (tickets)

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, email, interpreter

scheme:
[image]

Hi. This scheme describe my problem. I want the message received from the client to the e mail former interpreted and added to mysql table. Of course this record will be displayed at crm and when consultant will reply, his reply  add to mysql table and send re-email to customer.
The principle of operation basically taken from Redmine, but I do not know how to create such an interpretation.

Please, help me ! :)

Oh.. and .. PHP, MySQL, jQuery - this is it!

Comment: This is not a consuling service, we aren't here to design your application for you. If you don't know how to do this, you need to hire a qualified programmer and system administrator to implement it.

Comment: oh my God .. I am learning ... it is not my job